# Qt and "No such slot" error

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qobject

I wrote the class and add a slot:

```
class graphShow : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  graphShow(){}
public slots:
  void upd(QGraphicsScene &S);
};
```

Implementation of `graphShow::upd` is here:

```
void graphShow::upd(QGraphicsScene &S) {
    QGraphicsTextItem* pTextItem = S.addText("Test");
    pTextItem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
}
```

Connection:

```
graphShow gr;
QPushButton* p1 = new QPushButton("Show");
/*...*/
QObject::connect(p1,SIGNAL(clicked()),&gr,SLOT(upd(&scene);));
```

During compiling I have no errors but when program starts I see this message:

> Object::connect: No such slot graphShow::upd(&scene); in main.cpp:93

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, you doing it wrong. You could not connect signal without arguments to slot with argument. For your case you should use [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up connection in the following way:

```
QObject::connect(p1, SIGNAL(clicked()), &gr, SLOT(upd(QGraphicsScene &)));
```

However this also may not wark, because Qt docs state:

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving
>   slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it
>   receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)